# include errno if not accessed directly

Tags: c, errno

Do i need to include `errno.h` even if i don't access `errno` directly? Eg.

```
void *mem = malloc(16384);
if (mem == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I tried a simple piece of code like this without including `errno.h` and it worked, but i'm not sure if it's OK to do this. Maybe `errho.h` is also included in other libraries like `stdlib.h` and so i don't need to explicitly include it myself?

Comment: If you don't access any of the functionality, why would you need to include it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `<errno.h>` if you use only `perror()`.

From the *Linux Programmer's Manual*:

```
NAME
       perror - print a system error message

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdio.h>

       void perror(const char *s);

       #include <errno.h>

       const char *sys_errlist[];
       int sys_nerr;
       int errno;
```

This means that you need `<errno.h>` only if you use `sys_errlist`, `sys_nerr` or `errno`. Note that `sys_errlist` and `sys_nerr` are BSD extensions.

Similar entries can also be found on the C99 standard.

> 7.19.10.4 The perror function
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> void perror(const char *s);
> ```

And you need `<errno.h>` only if you use the following:

> 7.5 Errors
>
> 1 The header `<errno.h>` defines several macros, all relating to the reporting of error conditions.
>
> 2 The macros are
>
> ```
> EDOM
> EILSEQ
> ERANGE
> ```
>
> which expand to integer constant expressions with
>   type `int`, distinct positive values, and which are suitable for use in
>   `#if` preprocessing directives; and
>
> ```
> errno
> ```
>
> which expands to a modifiable lvalue <sup>175)</sup> that has type `int`, the value of which is set to a positive
>   error number by several library functions.
>
> [...]
>
> 4
>   Additional macro definitions, beginning with `E` and a digit or `E` and an
>   uppercase letter, <sup>177)</sup> may also be specified by the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

- malloc() requires stdlib.h
- perror() requires stdio.h
- exit() requires stdlib.h

So nothing here requires errno.h